# jar executable can't find binary which is included in jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, processbuilder

I'm running a cmd tool from a java app with `ProcessBuilder`, it's located in `src/main/resources/external/name-of-tool/name-of-tool.exe`. When I build jar with maven and try to run it I get an IOException with message `CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. I checked jar file and the `.exe` is right there in `external/name-of-tool` folder. In the code, I'm using a string for how I'd normally run a cmd tool, and it works fine in the IDE (I removed `src/main/resources` before building, assuming a relative path from "root" of the jar would work, so just ```external/name-of-tool/name-of-tool.exe, but I tried both ways). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not believe that your operation system is able to run executables that are inside a JAR file.

Comment: It is, I'd assumed processbuilder automatically means a cmd instance, turns out I had to specify I wanted a cmd

Comment: "*It is*"? you're saying that your OP sys is able to run EXE files inside a JAR file?

Comment: no, the java code runs that

Comment: but from documentation of `ProcessBuilder`, the provided command is "*the specified operating system program and arguments*" and I do not believe that an EXE inside a JAR is considered a "system program" (usually, for Windows, such executables are found by searching the directories listed on the `PATH` variable or the path given with the command - AFAIK neither accepts a path to inside a JAR) - the EXE will have to be extracted to the file system to be executed

Comment: "java code runs that" - not directly; it delegates to the operating system, similar to having the command and its arguments typed on the systems CLI  (aka Command Prompt for Windows)

Comment: An “embedded resource” is an entry inside a zip file. You can’t “run” executables that are contained in zip files, they first need to be extracted. You should also not be referencing “src” in you code, it won’t exist once your app is packaged

Comment: *(I removed src/main/resources before building...)* Don't do that. That's essential to Maven's packaging process. Anything in there will end up in the right place at the root of the jar. So you can address that as `getResourceAsStream("/foo.exe")` for extraction. I suggest `java.io.tmpdir`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to specify I need to run a cmd, I assumed ProcessBuilder automatically meant a cmd instance

Comment: The problem is that you've got a situation where you *cannot* execute the app in your jar. You need to extract that resource somewhere first and *then* run it with `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Please specify how you ran the cmd